# Mosquitto library usage with iOS

Tags: ios, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to use the MQTT protocol and am an amateur with this. I tried the objective-C code over Mosquitto library using MQTTKit (https://github.com/jmesnil/MQTTKit).

I am able to use it to publish messages to some test servers and things are working fine but still I have some basic questions, not so clear to me:

1. Does Mosquitto library include web sockets too underneath?
2. Is it possible to create a connection, subscribe to a topic and then server can also publish messages to device with realtime behavior? In other words, can we use it for real time communication between server and client (the iOS device in this case) bidirectional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The mosquitto library does not support websockets, it is mqtt only.
2. Yes, mqtt is a bidirectional protocol. I believe there are difficulties with keeping a long term socket open on iOS that mean it isn't as straightforward to support as you might like. I'm not familiar with iOS at all though.

Comment: Thanks Ralight. One more question in this regard. Mosquitto library is a broker (which I understand as a client). So i can publish to a server and subscribe to a server using this. How to implement a server providing support for handling messages with MQTT? Could it be any server or specific to MQTT? Is there any test server which we can use for publish and subscription purpose with minimal customization. Any links or sample code will be helpful.

Comment: The mosquitto project provides a broker called mosquitto. It also provides a client library called libmosquitto. You can use test.mosquitto.org:1883 for testing. You should be able to find lots of examples by searching.

Answer (score 0):

1.the mosquitto library of javascript has support websocket. you can go http://mosquitto.org/download/ to download.

2.mosquitto support MQTT protocol. When the connection was established, the mosquitto will send PINGREQ message for keep heartbeat.(the keep alive time please see MQTT protocol). the MQTT protocol is Publish / Subscribe (PubSub) model.So the server(broker) is central. Client subscribe topic, other client can receive message, and clietn can publish message to the another topic.That's all, you only need to set appropriate topic.